# In a Xcode project with multiple targets, if you build a target for release, it will build also the target dependancy for release. Can I avoid this?

Tags: objective-c, swift, xcode, cocoa

I have a macOS Xcode project with the following targets:

1)Cocoa Objective-C static library (scheme set to debug)

2)Cocoa Objective-C Example App (the static library is a target dependency)

3)Cocoa Swift Example App (the static library is a target dependency)

If I build the example apps for release, it will always pick the release version of the static library, while I would like to pick the debug version in all circumstances. I have tested this behaviour with this code in the library:

```
#ifdef DEBUG
        self.server = @"https://handler-staging.xxxxxxxxxxxx.com";
#else
        self.server = @"https://handler.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.com";
#endif
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: What about adding another discriminant, like `PRODUCTION` (or `STAGING` if you prefer)?

Comment: Why would you need something like this? What's the context?

Comment: I would like the library to be compiled for DEBUG regardless of the settings of the example targets, but I would like to build the library as RELEASE if I select the library scheme and select RELEASE in the scheme settings. thanks